# Magnetohydrodynamic equations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics

Is there any literature related to Slip boundary conditions of friction type for magnetohydrodynamic equations? As there is some results for Navier-Stokes equations with slip boundary conditions of friction type but no result I can find for MHD. Can we use the slip boundary conditions of friction type for MHD specially for its weak solutions. Especially, for weak solutions of MHD equations.

Comment: There are several obstruction to the use of slip/no slip boundary conditions. The problem with de boundary conditions on the magnetic field is about preserving the divergence free property through the evolution, which may not happen for this kind of boundary conditions.

Comment: @ToGle Many thanks.